# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'app.js' imported from index.js

Tags: javascript

Description:

I'm encountering an issue while trying to run my Node.js application with nodemon using ECMAScript modules (ESM). The error message I'm getting is:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'app.js' imported from /Users/oumarmauret/Documents/AkalanSchool/models/index.js
```

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

const __filename = path.basename(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
import configJson from '../config/config.json' assert { type: 'json' };
const config = configJson[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(async (file) => {
    const { default: model } = await import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model(sequelize, DataTypes);
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default db;
```

And here's the content of my app.js file:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import AppError from './utils/appError.js';
import globalErrorHandler from './controllers/errorController.js';
import path from 'path';
import { getCurrentUser } from './controllers/googleAuth.js';
import { getFacebookUserData } from './controllers/facebookAuth.js';
import session from 'express-session';
import xss from 'xss-clean';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import config from './config/config.json' assert { type: 'json' };

const app = express();

// Import des routes
import adminRoutes from './routes/admin.routes.js';
import oauthRoutes from './routes/oauth.routes.js';
import categoriesRoutes from './routes/categories.routes.js'; // Ajout de cette ligne
import downloadRoutes from './routes/courseDownload.routes.js';
import coursesRoutes from './routes/course.routes.js';
import moduleRoutes from './routes/module.routes.js';
import LessonRoutes from './routes/lesson.routes.js';
import QuizRoutes from './routes/quiz.routes.js';
import QuestionRoutes from './routes/question.routes.js';
import AnswerRoutes from './routes/answer.route.js';
import userRoutes from './routes/user.routes.js';
import reviewRoutes from './routes/review.routes.js';
import statsRoutes from './routes/enrolment.routes.js';

app.enable('trust proxy');
app.set('views', path.join(import.meta.url, './views'));

// 1) GLOBAL MIDDLEWARES
// Set security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.static(path.join(import.meta.url, 'views')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(import.meta.url, 'public')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('signin.ejs');
});

// Limit requests from same API
const limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 5,
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  //one hour
  message:
    'Trop de demandes provenant de cette IP, veuillez réessayer dans une heure !',
});

app.use('/api/', limiter);

// Body parser, reading data from body into req.body
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'Keep it secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: false },
  })
);

app.get('/myaccount', getCurrentUser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const fullname = res.locals.user.fullname;
    const message = `Hello ${fullname} (Connected via Google)`;
    res.send(message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user data:', error.message);
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});

app.get('/myprofile', getFacebookUserData, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const fullname = res.locals.user.fullname;
    const message = `Hello ${fullname} (Connected via Facebook)`;
    res.send(message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user data:', error.message);
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});

//Data sanitization against SQL query injection

//Data sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss());

// Initialize Sequelize
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'].database,
  config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'].username,
  config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'].password,
  config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development']
);

// Check database connection
async function sequelizeDatabaseConnect() {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connexion à la base de données réussie.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur de connexion à la base de données :', error);
  }
}

sequelizeDatabaseConnect();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(import.meta.url, 'uploads')));
app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.requestTime = new Date().toISOString();
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use('/api/v1/courses', categoriesRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/courses/downloads', downloadRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/courses', coursesRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/courses', LessonRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/courses', moduleRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/courses', QuizRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/courses', QuestionRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/courses', AnswerRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/admins', adminRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/auth', oauthRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/stats', statsRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviewRoutes);

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(
    new AppError(`Impossible de trouver ${req.originalUrl} sur ce serveur`, 404)
  );
});

app.use(globalErrorHandler);

export default app;
```

My package.json file contains the following scripts for starting the application:

```
{
  "name": "akalanschool",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --experimental-modules server.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Oumar MAURET",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^7.1.5",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "firebase": "^10.8.0",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "html-to-text": "^9.0.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5",
    "nanoid": "^5.0.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.7",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.35.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.2",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.4"
  }
}
```

I suspect the issue might be related to the way nodemon is configured to work with ECMAScript modules. Could anyone please help me understand why I'm encountering this error and suggest a solution to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have restarted the server multiple times and made modifications to the script, including adding nodemon --experimental-modules server.js, believing that it would solve the problem. I expected to resolve this issue and understand why it's happening so that I can handle it better in the future.

Comment: I'm guessing it's `await import(path.join(__dirname, file))` that is throwing the error?

Comment: Hello:)

It seems that you are importing the `app.js` file but the path is incorrect.
You should revise your project structure.

Comment: you do realise `.forEach(async (file) => {` is going to cause you issues further down of course

Comment: check what `path.join(__dirname, file)` results in ... `app.js` ... it needs to be `./app.js'`

Comment: I think the error is `const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);` should be `const __dirname = path.dirname(import.meta.url);`